# Garbarge Collection in Ruby with Circular Object References

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

I'm having an issue with garbage collection in Ruby where an object that I think should be garbage collection is not being garbage collected.

```rb
require 'ruby-mass'

def find_dependencies(_object_id,_mapped = {})
  mapped = _mapped
  points_to_object = Mass.references(Mass[_object_id])
  ids = points_to_object.keys.map{|x| /\#(\d*)/.match(x).captures.first.to_i}
  mapped[_object_id] = ids

  unmapped = ids - mapped.keys
  unmapped.each do |x|
    new_deps = find_dependencies(x,mapped)
    mapped.merge(new_deps)
  end
  mapped
end
```

Do some stuff that makes the objects, and find the relevant object ID. `GC.start`, then:

```
> find_dependencies(144789180)
=> {144789180=>[61895480, 144786340, 147807540],
 61895480=>[144789180],
 144786340=>[144789180],
 147807540=>[144789180]}
```

It looks like there is a circular reference pattern here, but it is all completely contained in these four objects, so the Mark-and-Sweep collector should find them and remove them.

So, either there is a bug in my find_dependencies_function, the Mass gem, or Ruby's garbage collector. How do I narrow this down to find out what the problem is and solve this memory leak?

Comment: Mark-and-sweep can't handle these sorts of things. To do this, you have to use WeakRef in those objects to allow the collector to remove the whole tree.

Comment: Why can't mark and sweep handle these things? I can see how they would slip through reference counting, but these shouldn't be marked, and should be collected, no?

Comment: I first have to ask -- how do you lose the object reference? Are there absolutely *no* other references to the subobjects?

Comment: I am creating the objects, and caching them in a class variable (@@cache),, and then clearing that cache variable (@@cache = nil), yet these still seem to live on. I'm not positive there are no other references, but it looks like it given what I am seeing with Ruby-mass

Comment: That's the key. If there's another reference to *any* of those four objects *anywhere* else, the entire tree will be forced to stay.

Comment: @Linuxios What? Mark-and-sweep is the textbook example of an automatic memory management scheme that handles circular references (as opposed to naive reference counting, which does not). What else might you mean by "these sorts of things"? Collecting still-reachable objects? Well, that's true but kind of self-defeating, not collecting reachable objects is a core requirement for all GCs.

Comment: @delnan: Exactly. And I'm saying that if theres a reference to any of these objects anywhere else, it forces the entire tree to stay in memory.

Comment: @Linuxios Okay, then it's just your phrasing that confused me.

Comment: But calling Mass on those objects indicates that the only thing pointing to them is the object itself, so it seems like there is not a reference to these objects anywhere else.

Comment: Hi aaronjg, i had a similar problem with the .Net-GC and the circular refence can not be solved by the reference count gc -> see this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/01/27/back-to-basics-reference-counting-garbage-collection.aspx

Comment: tingel2k - But ruby uses a mark and sweep, and not reference counting, so it should be able to pick this up.

Comment: @aaronjg: it's hard for me to tell what's going on here without seeing reproducible code containing objects that cause the problem. Could you add that to your example code?

Answer (score 4):

The GC in Ruby works essentially like so:

1. Mark all global objects as live.
2. Sweep through objects, garbage collect unless a parent is live.

So, in the case of a circular reference, A holding onto B holding onto A would get GC'd because neither is being held by a live object.

Per the comments, something is necessarily holding onto the object somewhere... Or maybe Mass is catching RangeError or something...

```
>> a = {}
=> {}
>> a[:a] = a
=> {:a=>{...}}
>> a.object_id
=> 2269556540
>> a = nil
=> nil
>> GC.start
=> nil
>> ObjectSpace._id2ref(2269556540)
RangeError: 0x8746af3c is recycled object
    from (irb):17:in `_id2ref'
    from (irb):17
```